# How to use regex to retrieve the content of attribute tag in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, regex, regexkitlite

I am new to iPhone development. I am using RegexkitLite framework to parse and retrieve the particular content from the Html source. I want to retrieve the content in the attribute tag. How should I give regex to achieve it? The Tag is

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="11-link-dkred-bold">This is stack overflow HTML</a>
```

How can I retrieve href content and value between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags?

Comment: Is there any alternate to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the output by using

```
<a href=([^<]*) class=\"11-link-dkred-bold\"><b>([^<]*)</a>"
```

I have used \ before the double quotes.Just like printing the " in print statement.

Answer (score 3):

Its recommended to use a HTML parser for such jobs.

If you want to use a regex you can try this:

```
<a href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)">([^<]*)</a>
```

First group will capture the href attribute value and second group will capture the text between the starting and closing tag.

Comment: I want to retrieve the content of the tag which has class="11-link-dkred-bold".I have changed your expression as <a href=([^=]*)>([^<]*)</a> because yours showed compile time error for using s.

Comment: Use: <a href ="([^"]*)" class="11-link-dkred-bold">([^<]*)</a>